# How can I loop through another form's combobox?

Tags: vb6

I'm seeking for some advices/tips/corrections on my code why it doesn't work on correctly.

I've got 2 forms.
Form1 with menubars (add type menubar), I want to make it loop through the combobox list (to check if there is no existing data can be added on the list) on the form2.
What I don't understand is why it's not working on form1? While when I'm testing my code on other project using 1 form it works. Can someone tell me what's wrong? and why?

Using 2 forms. This code will only add new type but doesn't check if there is exist data on the combo box :(

```
Private Sub mnuAYT_Click()
Dim TypeYacht As String 'Type of yacht added
Dim blnItem As Boolean
Dim intItem As Integer

' - - - - - - - LOOP THROUGHT the combo box all items - - - - - - -

blnItem = False
intItem = 0
Do Until blnItem = True Or intItem = NewCharter.cmbTypeYacht.ListCount
    If TypeYacht = NewCharter.cmbTypeYacht.List(intItem) Then
        blnItem = True
    End If
    intItem = intItem + 1
Loop
    If blnItem = True Then
     MsgBox TypeYacht & " " & "is already exist", vbInformation, "Yacht Type Match"
     NewCharter.cmbTypeYacht.ListIndex = intItem - 1
    Else
    NewCharter.cmbTypeYacht.AddItem NewCharter.cmbTypeYacht.Text
    MsgBox "Successfully added new Yacht Type", vbInformation, "Successfully Added"
    End If
End Sub
```

by the way this is my code using only 1 form (add's and check if there is exist data)

```
Dim TypeYacht As String 'Type of yacht added
Dim blnItem As Boolean
Dim intItem As Integer

' ----------------------------- LOOP THROUGHT the combo box all items -------------------------

blnItem = False
intItem = 0
TypeYacht = cmbTypeYacht.Text

Do Until blnItem = True Or intItem = cmbTypeYacht.ListCount
    If TypeYacht = cmbTypeYacht.List(intItem) Then
        blnItem = True
    End If
    intItem = intItem + 1
Loop
    If blnItem = True Then
     MsgBox TypeYacht & " " & "is already exist", vbInformation, "Yacht Type Match"
     cmbTypeYacht.ListIndex = intItem - 1
    Else
    cmbTypeYacht.AddItem cmbTypeYacht.Text
    MsgBox "Successfully added new Yacht Type", vbInformation, "Successfully Added"

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`NewCharter` must contain a reference to a valid opened instance of the `NewCharter` form.

VB6 allows you to access a form by its class name, without explicitly creating it. This can lead to confusion. You should always create forms and pass references explicitly.

In one form, you must have a variable of type `NewCharter`. Then you must create the second form and tell the first form you did it. E.g.,

```
Dim another_form As NewCharter
Set another_form = New NewCharacter
```

Then you use `another_form` instead of `NewCharter` in your existing code.

Comment: sir, base on what u answered i put those code u gave me on form1 where my menubar(under this) is but somehow doesnt add new data and check if the data already exist.

Comment: @blackmaler The code I gave you only creates a form and stores the reference. You must make sure the created form contains some data at the point where you try to access it. I don't know how you fill your form with data, you do. Try extending the code with `another_form.Visible = True` and triggering methods that pull in data. Then click your `mnuAYT`.

Comment: i get the data from form2 by user input cmbTypeYacht.text
and form1 got the munebar(mnuAYT), on "cmbTypeYacht" there are some data already exist so thats why i need to loop it throught the list to make sure it doesnt duplicate anything already exist.